# v-img doesn't gets rendered in a functional component - Vuetify 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I've installed `@nuxtjs/vuetify` and trying to use `v-img` inside a functional component:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'Logo',
  functional: true,
  render(createElement, { parent }) {
    const image = createElement('v-img', {
      props: {
        src: require('@/assets/images/logo.svg'),
        width: parent.$mq === 'lg' ? 200 : 170
      }
    })

    return createElement(
      'nuxt-link',
      {
        props: {
          to: '/'
        }
      },
      [image]
    )
  }
})
```

While in `dev` environment, image tag gets rendered correctly:

```
<div class="v-responsive v-image" style="width:200px;">...</div>
```

But when i build my app for production, it outputs:

```
<v-img></v-img>
```

It's clearly doesn't gets rendered. If i use `v-img` inside a stateful component, then it works in production. What's wrong?

**UPDATE 1**

If i pass `v-btn` in `createElement()` as first arg, the it gets rendered both in dev and production. Something wrong with `v-img`?